# Avoiding code repetition without using multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, multiple-inheritance

```
class A : N
{
     void sinefunc()
     {
           //some stuff here
     }
}

class B : N
{

    void sinefunc()
    {
        //some stuff here
    }
}

class C : N
{ 
    void sinefunc()
    {
         //some stuff here
    }
}
```

The `sinefunc()` is a common function. but, the classes A,B and C exists in different 
projects under a solution. The classes already inherit a common class N and now,

1. To avoid code repetition, the `sinefunc()` can be moved outside of these classes.
2. But, since Multiple inheritance is not allowed. what is the efficient method or 
   feasible way to make the function common ? (Please note that I don't want to put the `sinefunc()`
   in class N. Its been already written and I don't want to disturb that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (Please note that I dont want to put the sinefunc() in class N. Its
>   been already written and I dont want to disturb that class)

**Without moving the function to `N` class, you can't do that**. You can have an interface which will have the method signature, but then you have to define implementation at each class.

One way to do it would be to **write an extension method to class `N`** and you can use that in the inherited classes.

EDIT:

Define a static class to hold the extension method like:

```
public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static void sinefunc(this N obj)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Later you can call it like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A objA = new A();
    objA.sinefunc();
}
```

**Remember to include the namespace which is holding the extension method, otherwise it will not be visible.**  You can read more at: [Extension methods MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: Extension method is the "C#onic" way to add the function to multiple subclasses of N without changing N.  That said, if you have multiple subclasses with identical functionality it seems like moving it into N really is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the extension methods Habib. pretty new here.. some code samples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Habib.. it was helpful. trying to implement it now.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an intermediate class which acts as a facade to class `N`:

```
class A : X {    }

class B : X {    }

class C : X {    }

class X : N
{
     protected void sinefunc()
     {
           //some stuff here
     }
}
```

Comment: you mean the multilevel inheritance ?

Comment: Thanks you for an another way!

Answer (score 0):

if The sinefunc() is a common function, why don't you put it into another class. For example, you can make it a static method in Utility class